# Ошибка C2664: невозможно преобразовать параметр 1 в const std::allocator

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector, visual-studio-2012

```
struct Expression {
    Expression(std::string token) : token(token) {};
    Expression(std::string token, Expression a) : token(token), args( a ) {};
    Expression(std::string token, Expression a, Expression b) : token(token), args( a, b ) {};

    std::string token;
    std::vector<Expression> args;
};
```

Ошибка в 3 строке.

Собственно, сама ошибка:
error C2664: std::vector<_Ty>::vector(const std::allocator<_Ty> &): невозможно преобразовать параметр 1 из "Expression" в "const std::allocator<_Ty> &"

Из-за чего ошибка? Как исправить? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Загляните в справочник и посмотрите, какие конструкторы есть у класса `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Expression(std::string token, Expression a) : token(token), args( a ) {};` заменить на:

```
Expression(std::string token, Expression a): token(token) {
    this->args.push_back(a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В списке инициализации конструктора это можно сделать только начиная с С++14. Для этого надо добавить фигурные скобки

```
Expression(std::string token, Expression a) : token(token), args({ a }) {}
Expression(std::string token, Expression a, Expression b) : token(token), args({ a, b }) {}
```

Или можно даже без круглых скобок

```
Expression(std::string token, Expression a) : token(token), args{ a } {}
Expression(std::string token, Expression a, Expression b) : token(token), args{ a, b } {}
```

Comment: С фигурными скобками выдает ошибку.

Comment: @Josif Brodsky: "Выдает ошибку" не является осмысленным описанием проблемы. Скорее всего вы просто используете замшело-устаревший компилятор .

Comment: Ну если VS 2012 - "замшело-устаревший компилятор", тогда да.

Comment: @JosifBrodsky: Вы ответ читали? Или просто скопировали код? `В списке инициализации конструктора это можно сделать только начиная с С++14.` И теперь глядите что поддерживает VS2012

Comment: Вы добавили эту строку только 10 минут назад. Когда бы я успел прочитать?